# Dispose Device.StartTimer, if current page is reinitialized from the mainpage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**I want to stop Device.StartTimer when my current page is re-initialize from the App.cs page, but every time when page is re-initialize Device.Starttimer create new instance and function is calling multiple times.**

from the links and references i get to know that it will not stop until return statement not execute, but in my case how to execute return statement outside the method, that i can not understand.

**Below is my cs page code.**

```
public partial class MediaScreen : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new List<string>
        { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" };

        public static readonly List<string> videoExtensions = new List<string> {
            ".WAV", ".MID", ".MIDI", ".WMA", ".OGG", ".RMA", //etc
            ".AVI", ".MP4", ".DIVX", ".WMV", //etc
            };

        int i = 0;

        DisplayInfo mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        public MediaScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                StartPlaying();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        public bool StartPlaying()
        {
             CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();
            if (i == App.localStorage.Playlist.PlayListItems.Count)
            {
                i = 0;
                StartPlaying();
                return false;
            }

            var data = App.localStorage.Playlist.PlayListItems[i].MediaLibrary;
            string fileName = App.path + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(data.Url);

            if (ImageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                // process image
                imgPlayer.IsVisible = true;
                imgPlayer.Source = fileName;

                videoPlayer.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(fileName);
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaItemFinished += finishVideo;
                    videoPlayer.IsVisible = true;
                    imgPlayer.IsVisible = false;
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                }
            }
            i++;

         Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds
                   (data.Duration), StartPlaying);
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a stoppable timer instead. It has 2 goals: it can be stopped, it can be rescheduled (if it didn't start yet you can reschedule it):

Schedule example:

```
public StoppableTimer<object> timerScheduled; //object is param type you want

public void LaunchTimer()
{
            if (timerScheduled == null)
            {
                timerScheduled = new StoppableTimer<object>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), OnTimerStart);
                timerScheduled.Start(null); //whatever param
            }
            else
            {
                //relaunch
                timerScheduled.Stop();
                timerScheduled.Start(control);
            }
}
```

So when you need to cancel the timer just call `timerScheduled.Stop();`

Your callback:

```
private void OnTimerStart(object p)
{
   //StartPlaying - do your stuff
}
```

Class:

```
 public class StoppableTimer<T> // T is the parameter you want to pass to timer
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan timespan;
        private readonly Action<T> callback;

        private CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

        public StoppableTimer(TimeSpan timespan, Action<T> callback)
        {
            this.timespan = timespan;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        public void Start(T param)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = this.cancellation; // safe copy
            Device.StartTimer(this.timespan,
                () => {
                    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return false;
                    this.callback.Invoke(param);
                    return false; // or true for periodic behavior
                });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.cancellation, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, exactly I just wanted to do the same thing. it works properly.